# The Countdown Timer in Android studio skips some of the seconds within the time interval

Tags: countdowntimer

I read about the problem a day ago where the problem occurs with people but when it comes to the final second. I kept noticing in my timer that the as it counts down it sometimes skips a second, some suggested changing the interval from 1000ms to 500ms others said make it 900. And there are those who suggested making your own Timer.

My timer is a bit big as it contains two smaller timers within it, that count down individual minutes within the total time and I activate an animation during those times. So basically I am asking what approach should I take to for a time critical counter that is 100% accurate?

This is my code:

```
        private void startTimer() {
        Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "CHECK","Entered startTimer() method");
        millisInFuture = mTimeLeftInMillis;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 900) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
                millisPassed = millisInFuture - mTimeLeftInMillis;
                progress = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / millisInFuture);
                pb.setProgress(progress);
                pb2.setProgress(0);
                pb3.setProgress(0);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //Key: 60 sec
                if (millisInFuture == 480000) {
                    if (millisPassed <= 60000 || (millisPassed > 180000 && millisPassed <= 240000) || (millisPassed > 300000 && millisPassed <= 360000 || (millisPassed > 420000 && millisPassed <= 480000))) {
//                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
//                        stepupimage.setAnimation(animation);

                        Log.println(Log.ASSERT,"CHECK","Check that the first if statement of key 60 is entered");
                        statusIfUp();
                        time_of_stage = (millisInFuture - millisPassed) % 60000;
                        progress2 = (int) (time_of_stage*100 / 60000);
                        Log.println(Log.VERBOSE,"CHECK","TIME OF STAGE = "+time_of_stage);
                        Log.println(Log.VERBOSE,"CHECK","progress2= "+progress2);
                        pb2.setProgress(progress2);
                        updateStageUpCount();
                        upArrowAnimation();

                        setflowrate();
}
}
    @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(tool1mode1.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                avd2.stop(); avd3.stop();
                try {
                pb.setProgress(100); pb2.setProgress(0); pb3.setProgress(0);
                stage_timer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                stage_timer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progressBar2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                progressBar2.setProgress(0);
                progressBar.setTranslationY(60);
                progressBar2.setTranslationY(60);
                flow.setTranslationY(60);
                animation1.cancel(); animation2.cancel();
                //Vibration


                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                        ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(150, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                    } else {
                        ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(new long[]{150}, new int[]{VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK}, -1));
                    }
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }.start();

    }
```

So to summarize: I have  a big timer and two small timers that count certain intervals within the larger timer. Now the *CountDownTimer* class that is provided by Android skips a second or two at times during the count down. I want to fix this problem and don't know how, I would have just rolled with it but unfortunately the one I'm making the app for requires it to be 100% accurate as the application is time critical.

Note: pb, pb2, pb3, are progress bars of the timers (1st is the big one, 2nd and 3rd alternate for the second timer)